# Is there any way to know if an arraylist contains a piece of text?

Tags: java, arrays, string, arraylist, contains

I have an arraylist with several items. Let's say they are: "DARK BROWN", "BLUE", "GREEN",....

Is there any way to look for if there's the string "DARK" in some of my items? I know that contains does this but it only does if the string is exactly. My idea is to look for a text that starts as one of my items but it hasn't all the last characters.

I have thougth in do a loop like:

```
for(int i=0;i<arraylist.size;i++){
  String s = arraylist.get(i);
  if (s.startsWith(mytext)){
   do something
  }
}
```

but it seems to be a very slow method because the arraylist can contain a lot of elements. Any better ideas?

**EDIT**

Just to be sure you understand my point. I want to know if an item of my arraylist contains an element that starts with some text and to get the complete text of that element. ArrayList.contains is a boolean. If I need to retrieve information I will have to use IndexOf or so but this function gives me null if I put "brown"

**EDIT 2**

This is for you auselen:

Arraylist (5000 elements or so):

- "David's cat is in his bedroom"
- "I like the moon"
- "I want to travel to Mars"
- "My ball is red"
- "They always forget about Antarctida"
- ...

I want to know if there's an element that starts with "I want to" and then retrieve the rest of the element.

Comment: *"but it seems to be a very slow method because.."* ..the profiler is suggesting that is where the bottleneck occurs.  (Is about the only valid ending to that sentence.)

Comment: The data structure suited best for what I think you are doing is a [prefix tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie), a so called trie.

Comment: Correct i too, stated below that a trie is best, but do you have millions of words? No then look at my answer

Comment: Sort the array list and use some kind of divide an conquer search

Comment: How many is a lot of strings?

Comment: Can you give a better example of string matching you are mentioning?

Comment: Do it in anyway, this can't be slow. A modern Android phone can move 2GB of data in a second.

Comment: Solution with `binarysearch` added, there you go!

Comment: if you exactly know what needs to be searched then, hashing is a very good idea, based on what effects your search, otherwise you could go for sequence initialization process, In both the approaches I want that you do some kind of pre-processing of the string while you get it and then store it in such a fashion that it could be easier and faster at search time,,for eg: if you know that you want to search for dark,, while creating the arrayList keep a check on that,, and just add them to some another list,, or just increment the counter (whatever you need..!),,

Comment: For the second approach,, SIP, just create a Map<Integer,String>, now while reading the sentences whenever you get some new word that is not already present in the Map<> just , just add that word with an incremented sequence key-INT for the previously existing last entry's key--><LastKey+1,Word>,, This will eventually help you converting the sentences into an sequence of integers,, after the entire Map is created,,all sentences are converted, just pass the keyset of the Map to a treeset with your own customized comp,that will put the required sequences at top or at last,with their count too..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> it seems to be a very slow method because the arraylist can contain a lot of elements.

Like, a million?

```
Nov 30, 2012 10:05:20 AM test.t100.t001.ArrayListSpeed main
INFO: Creating entries.
Nov 30, 2012 10:05:21 AM test.t100.t001.ArrayListSpeed main
INFO: Searching..
Nov 30, 2012 10:05:21 AM test.t100.t001.ArrayListSpeed main
INFO: Searching 'dark' 333716
Nov 30, 2012 10:05:21 AM test.t100.t001.ArrayListSpeed main
INFO: Searching 'light' 333333
Nov 30, 2012 10:05:22 AM test.t100.t001.ArrayListSpeed main
INFO: Searching 'plain' 332951
```

### Code

```
package test.t100.t001;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class ArrayListSpeed {

    public static String[] PREFIX = {"Dark ", "Light ", "Plain "};
    public static String[] COLOR = {"Red", "Green", "Blue"};

    public static String getColor(Random r) {
        int val = r.nextInt(COLOR.length);
        return COLOR[val];
    }

    public static String getPrefix(Random r) {
        int val = r.nextInt(PREFIX.length);
        return PREFIX[val];
    }

    public static int countPrefixes(ArrayList<String> list, String prefix) {
        int count = 0;
        for (String val : list) {
            if (val.toLowerCase().startsWith(prefix.toLowerCase())) {
                count++;
            }
        }
        return count;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Logger logger = Logger.getAnonymousLogger();
        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        Random r = new Random();
        logger.log(Level.INFO, "Creating entries.");
        for (int ii=0; ii<1000000; ii++) {
            list.add( getPrefix(r) + getColor(r) );
        }
        logger.log(Level.INFO, "Searching..");
        logger.log(Level.INFO, 
                "Searching 'dark' " + countPrefixes(list,"dark"));
        logger.log(Level.INFO, 
                "Searching 'light' " + countPrefixes(list,"light"));
        logger.log(Level.INFO, 
                "Searching 'plain' " + countPrefixes(list,"plain"));
    } 
}
```

Comment: Logger with milliseconds woul be great ;-)

Comment: I don't know how many time it will be looking because I don't have the arraylist with all the items but I was afraid of because it's for an android device so the power of processing is limited and it has to be in less than a second (the user can't notice that the app is "looking for a solution". It has to notice that there's a solution when It press the button). When I looked at my code I thought "this is really dirty. There must be an easy way" so I post this. I don't see any differences between your solution and mine.

Comment: *"I don't see any differences between your solution and mine."*  Mine compiles & runs, and can therefore sweep aside wrong statements like *"it seems to be a very slow method"*.  3 million entries were searched in less than 2 seconds.  5000 should take <1/60th of a second.  Run the code on a phone and give us the numbers, I doubt they will be much different there.

Comment: And my code also compiles. What I mean is that I have a loop for as you and we both check all the arraylist. When I wrote the question I was thinking about if Java has something like String a = "example" + anyletter (as like in sql) and then indexof will be retrieve it well

Comment: **Run the code on a phone and give us the numbers..**  That might help prove what you are saying.  So far, it seems like 'noise'.

Comment: I had few time these days. After running your code and akuhn's code I can say that the speed is the same. Because you answered before and your code don't need to be ordered the point is for you. Time to search the last entry with 10.000 elements: 330 ms on Galaxy SII

Answer (score 2):

Keep the strings in a sorted(!) array and use `binarysearch` to find the insertion point of your prefix. The matches will be at that point, if at all.

Performance if this is *O(log n)* instead of *O(n)*, you should find it to be much faster, in particular for large data sets.

```
import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;
import java.util.Arrays;
import org.junit.Test;

public class ContainsPrefix {

    public static String findWithPrefix(String[] data, String prefix) {
        int n = Arrays.binarySearch(data, prefix);
        if (n < 0) n = -1 - n;
        // Loop here if you want to find all matches ...
        if (!data[n].startsWith(prefix)) return null;
        return data[n];
    }


    @Test
    public void shouldFindStringWithPrefix() {
        String[] data = { //
                "David's cat is in his bedroom", //
                "I like the moon", //
                "I want to travel to Mars", //
                "My ball is red", //
                "They always forget about Antarctida", //
                "..." //
            };
        Arrays.sort(data);
        String found = findWithPrefix(data, "I want to");
        assertEquals("I want to travel to Mars", found);

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Either do it like you have done it, or it gets much more complex.
There is a search structure called "trie" , but this is complex.

You could gain a bit by having an array of a- z pointing to the start position in your sorted ArrayList of the first letter. Then you only have to search within the words that start with the same letter.

Comment: Not more of 5000 elements. I'm not sure what will the size of the final arraylist.The second array you say it's a good idea because the array is sorted but it doesn't convince me. I have never thought that so silly thing to do with an arraylist would need extra code. Any way if there's no more good idea I think I will try it

Comment: Yes, either do your first solution, 5000 is not much, or if you want the fastest, take mine. ( a trie is to complex).

Answer (score -1):

Or you can use completly different approach. and wrap ArrayList and check upon list.add() for a match. And store it in some var for quick access. But if you have multiple values to search, then this approach is not good at all :).

Answer (score -3):

Here is an example of a function you could use with getting each item.  The speed of this is not really an increase.  Due to this being an arraylist there is not really a good way to do this.  There are better data structures for searching for parts of a string.

```
    public class RegionMatchesDemo {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String searchMe = "Green Eggs and Ham";
    String findMe = "Eggs";
    int searchMeLength = searchMe.length();
    int findMeLength = findMe.length();
    boolean foundIt = false;
    for (int i = 0; 
         i <= (searchMeLength - findMeLength);
         i++) {
       if (searchMe.regionMatches(i, findMe, 0, findMeLength)) {
          foundIt = true;
          System.out.println(searchMe.substring(i, i + findMeLength));
          break;
       }
    }
    if (!foundIt)
        System.out.println("No match found.");
  }
}
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with the question, at all.