# Finding index of an array while only knowing half the value

Tags: java, arrays

```
sender.sendMessage("Your referal code is: " + codestring[ArrayUtils.indexOf(namestring, value )]);
```

the value is equal to "name" plus a random number, how can i make this work without knowing the second part of this string array?

Comment: you really need to explain your question more clearly

Comment: What is the content of the array?

If only the correct element start with x then you can loop it and use string methods to examine if it begins correctly

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13636094/is-there-any-way-to-know-if-an-arraylist-contains-a-piece-of-text

Answer (score 1):

iterate through array and check for `startsWith()`

```
for(int index = 0 ; index < array.length ; index ++){
  if(array[index].startsWith(key)){return index;}
}
return -1; // not found
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't understand what you asked, but if you're trying to find a String, knowing only the first characters, you might use a regular expression to check, like:

```
for(String string: arrayOfStrings){
     if(string.matches("beginningOfString^[1-9]")){
        // your code
     }
}
```