# Simplest way to search an arraylist's entries for a piece of text?

Tags: java, search, arraylist

I've got an arraylist with (let's say) three entries.

```
The first entry: "Chris lives at 2320 alpha street"
The second entry: "Bob sleeps at 1900 bravo road"
The third entry: "Alex eats at 4231 charlie lane"
```

I'm trying to search through the arraylist, parse each line for a term the user enters, and return (to another part of my code) the index of the arraylist entry that contains the search term. In this example, the user types in "lane", the code searches all three, finds that the third entry contains the word "lane", and then returns a 2.

Currently, I'm using

```
if(addressBook.contains(searchModifier))//if their searchModifier is found anywhere in any of the strings
    return addressBook.indexOf(searchModifier);//return that index value
else
    return noEntry;
```

but this only works if there's an exact string match. I need to be able to search for just part of a string. Is there a simple way to do this? I checked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13636094/is-there-any-way-to-know-if-an-arraylist-contains-a-piece-of-text), but it seemed ridiculously complicated for what I'm trying to do - this is a 'hello world'-type program. I'm only searching through 3-4 entries at most! (not to mention the fact that I'm fairly new at this, and that code seemed awfully advanced...)

Comment: `it seemed ridiculously complicated` What exactly is complicated about that?

Comment: "I need a way to search for just part of the string." Do you have any sample input/output that shows this behavior? It is not exactly clear what you mean, as you are already using `contains` which does this.

Comment: I don't have 10k entries, I don't need to search prefixes, and I don't understand how I'd break up long sentences into the equivalent of 'prefixes' and 'colors'.

Comment: @clcto My issue is that I'm using .contains on the arraylist. It always returns a false because it's checking each entry for an exact match. I want to search for "lane", not "Alex eats at 4231 charlie lane".

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int i = 0; i < addressBook.size(); i++) {
  if (addressBook.get(i).contains(searchModified)) {
    return i;
  }
}
```

https://coderpad.io/279611

Comment: That's essentially what I'm doing. The problem is that it's returning false because it's trying to match the entire string, not just each individual part of it

Comment: @DanCallahan you are wrong, your code is different from this. You are matching entire strings because you don't loop through individual elements. This code matches individual parts because it loops through each element in addressBook ArrayList and sees if it contains the string. You can go ahead and play around with code in https://coderpad.io/279611 to see what I mean.

Answer (score 0):

Seems simple to me?

```
int idx = 0;
for(String s: addressBook){
    if( s.indexOf(searchModifier) != -1)
        break;
    idx++;
}
return idx;
```

Comment: I don't see how that's any different than what I'm doing, which has the same issue, doesn't it?

Comment: @DanCallahan no. It goes through each string in the list and looks for the `searchModifier`.